# How to dismiss ADAuthentication web view controller programmatically?

Tags: adal

I met the following issue after dismiss the webveiwcontroller from ADAL programmably, and next time when I re-launch the sign in flow, I was given the following errors:

```
error=Error with code: 13 Domain: ADAuthenticationErrorDomain ProtocolCode:(null)
Details:The user is currently prompted for credentials as result of another acquireToken request.
Please retry the acquireToken call later..
Inner error details: Error Domain=ADAuthenticationErrorDomain Code=13
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (ADAuthenticationErrorDomain error 13.)"
```

If I close the app completely and reopen it, the sign in flow works again. Is this a known issue and what could be used to work around this?

Thanks

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call ADAuthenticationBroker->cancel to make sure all the locks are released correctly.

Comment: I believe the answer is incomplete. You have to first dismiss ADAuthenticationViewController.m by calling dismissViewControllerAnimated, followed by the cancel method. dismissViewControllerAnimated is similar to closing a tab in browser in this case.