# Unable to get access to OneDrive in iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, onedrive

I'm trying to implement this [SDK](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-ios):

I did everything what was described in the doc and when I run the code:

```
 ODClient.client { [weak self] (client, error) in
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        if let client = client {
            print(client)
        }
    }
```

web view appears, I'm signing in into one drive account, but always receiving error:

> Error with code: 13 Domain: ADAuthenticationErrorDomain ProtocolCode:(null) Details:The user is currently prompted for credentials as result of another acquireToken request. Please retry the acquireToken call later.. Inner error details: Error Domain=ADAuthenticationErrorDomain Code=13 "(null)"

Does someone have the same issue and know hot to fix it?

Comment: Please checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27786447/how-to-dismiss-adauthentication-web-view-controller-programmatically.  It might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out by my own, first of all I had wrong redirect uri but, by the way, they also switched to api version 2

Here is some links. Maybe it will be helpful if someone will face with the same problems

[How to get token](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc)

[Their API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/?view=odsp-graph-online)

Comment: do you mean the onedrive-sdk is deprecated? What's the way to go in 2021? Thanks!